# Imagine module has no modeler attribute

Tags: python

l'm trying to do layerstack operations by using Python. However, l get stuck in an error.

here is example code:

```
import os,sys
from imagine import modeler

m = modeler.Model()

# Import Bands 1-7
ri1 = m.RasterInput(path + “/” + folderName + “_B1.TIF”)
ri2 = m.RasterInput(path + “/” + folderName + “_B2.TIF”)
ri3 = m.RasterInput(path + “/” + folderName + “_B3.TIF”)
ri4 = m.RasterInput(path + “/” + folderName + “_B4.TIF”)
ri5 = m.RasterInput(path + “/” + folderName + “_B5.TIF”)
ri6 = m.RasterInput(path + “/” + folderName + “_B6.TIF”)
ri7 = m.RasterInput(path + “/” + folderName + “_B7.TIF”)

stackbands = m.StackLayers(ri1,ri2,ri3,ri4,ri5,ri6,ri7)
outputFile = path + “/” + folderName + “-msi.img”
ro = m.RasterOutput(stackbands, outputFile)
m.Execute()
print “\nCreating MS image using bands 1-7…”
```

l got an error during `from imagine import modeler`and the error is here:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'modeler'
```

l installed `pip install imagine` but in imagine module has no modeler attribute.how can l solve this problem and l m using `Python 3.5 and Python 2.7`
and also l downloaded `Python Scripting with ERDAS IMAGINE Spatial Modeler 2014` and example python Scripts do not works due to missing attribute `modeler`.l hope l can find an answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, [imagine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imagine/1.1.0) [has no member `modeler`](https://github.com/unrar/imagine/blob/master/imagine/__init__.py). But that is the module you have installed from PyPI.

If you want to do [Python Scripting with ERDAS IMAGINE Spatial Modeler](https://intergraphgovsolutions.com/assets/white-paper/Python_Scripting_with_ERDAS_IMAGINE_Spatial_Modeler.sflb.pdf), you should try what it says in the documentation:

> For reference, the ERDAS IMAGINE Python libraries are installed in:
>   `$IMAGINE_HOME\usr\lib\Win32Release\python`

Comment: Damn, you were 7 seconds faster than me :D Did you know what happened, or did you search internet like me? Because we've provided almost exactly the same links :P

Comment: I searched PyPI and then the web :)

Comment: l have no erdas imagine installed on my pc so how can l use this folder? l do not want to install Erdas and that is why l m using python.l m lack of python knowledge ,by the way, l m still learning

Comment: You don't want to install Erdas but at the same time you want to use their API. That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install imagine` didn't install what you wanted. Instead, it used [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imagine/), a wrapper over Google Image Search library, which has no "modeler".

What you need to do is read [this](https://intergraphgovsolutions.com/assets/white-paper/Python_Scripting_with_ERDAS_IMAGINE_Spatial_Modeler.sflb.pdf), specially "Configuring Python for Use with Spatial Modeler" part (right after "Introduction"). It contains full description how to configure that tool with Python.

Also, as you can read there - there is no support for python3.x, only 2.7 line is supported.